# How can I create and type using a custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, keyboard-layout

This sounds like a very simple request, right? All I want to do is create a custom mapping of the keys on my keyboard to a set of Unicode characters ─ in fact, I just want to add a few special characters to the default English layout and that's it ─ and then be able to type using said mapping. I don't even necessarily need to download it on my computer; if I could just type using it online, akin to what [this website](https://www.typeit.org/) offers.

However, I've searched all over the internet, and this just doesn't seem to be possible. I've found [this website](http://www.keyboard-layout-editor.com/), but it appears to be pretty useless as it can only be integrated with physical keyboards. I have also found a bazillion font creators, but each of them requires me to draw each of the glyphs from scratch ─ something I have no interest in.

I have always found the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, but unfortunately, I'm on a Chromebook.

Is there anything at all that I can do? Or will I have to resort to copying and pasting the special characters that I regularly use every single time?